# How can I specify that Typescript generic T[K] is number type?

Tags: typescript, generics, keyof

I have a simple Typescript function like this:

```js
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): number {
  return obj[key]; // This line is not compiling.
  // Typescript will yell: "Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'number'."
}
```

My usage looks like this:

```js
const someObj = {
  myValue: 123,
  otherProperty: '321'
}

getProperty(someObj, 'myValue')
```

I won't know what structure of `someObj` will be.

My question is: How can I specify that `T[K]` is number type statically?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've updated my use case, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I won't know what structure of `someObj` will be.

Then TypeScript can't really help you with this. TypeScript's type checking is done at *compile-time*. If the structure of `someObj` will only be known at *runtime*, TypeScript can't make access to that structure typesafe. You'd need to know what the property keys and possible values for those properties are at compile-time.

For instance: In your example, the property names are strings and the property values are either strings or numbers (but not booleans or objects, etc.). You can declare a type indexed by strings (since all property names are ultimately strings or Symbols, in this case strings) where the property values are numbers or strings:

```
declare type SomeObjType = {
    [key: string]: number | string
};
```

and then `getProperty`is:

```
function getProperty<T extends SomeObjType>(obj: T, key: string): number | string {
  return obj[key];
}
```

and you can use it like this (in this case, I use `JSON.parse` to simulate receiving this data from outside the scope of the program):

```
const someObj: SomeObjType = JSON.parse(`{
  "myValue": 123,
  "otherProperty": "321"
}`);

console.log(getProperty(someObj, 'myValue'));
console.log(getProperty(someObj, 'otherProperty'));
```

[On the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20type%20SomeObjType%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20number%20%7C%20string%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Afunction%20getProperty%3CT%20extends%20SomeObjType%3E(obj%3A%20T%2C%20key%3A%20string)%3A%20number%20%7C%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20obj%5Bkey%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20someObj%3A%20SomeObjType%20%3D%20JSON.parse(%60%7B%0A%20%20%22myValue%22%3A%20123%2C%0A%20%20%22otherProperty%22%3A%20%22321%22%0A%7D%60)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(getProperty(someObj%2C%20'myValue'))%3B%0Aconsole.log(getProperty(someObj%2C%20'otherProperty'))%3B)

But that doesn't buy you much, and closes off the possibility that the property values are something other than numbers or strings.

You may need to just use `object`:

```
function getProperty(obj: object, key: string) {
  return obj[key];
}

const someObj = JSON.parse(`{
  "myValue": 123,
  "otherProperty": "321"
}`);

console.log(getProperty(someObj, 'myValue'));
console.log(getProperty(someObj, 'otherProperty'));
```

[On the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20getProperty(obj%3A%20object%2C%20key%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20obj%5Bkey%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20someObj%20%3D%20JSON.parse(%60%7B%0A%20%20%22myValue%22%3A%20123%2C%0A%20%20%22otherProperty%22%3A%20%22321%22%0A%7D%60)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(getProperty(someObj%2C%20'myValue'))%3B%0Aconsole.log(getProperty(someObj%2C%20'otherProperty'))%3B)

Comment: Wow, thank you for your detail explanation, `T extends SomeObjType` works for my use case! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If the objects you're working with are typed enough to have made their shape known to typescript, you can totally do this [[typescript playgrounds link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmB5ARgKxgXhgbwCgYYEBPANQEMAbAVyQC4YBGAJgGYAaImEKACyQAnAApCQAB2FRSTAOTtWzOQQC+AbgIEA5kihjJ00gAp4ydBk4w5ZKnSRyAlOpgB6V8U-EA7iCEBrCB09AykhGVNEVEwrOT5BUXEwmScXdxhvSgBLaiCCADNaMGAoLPAYXX0kowAeABUrAGkYJAAPKCQwABMIGAA5WmQhLOBQiHqAPgnjEEwmBph-JFkYRscmMEG0YXweYiE9WiEwXkwAbSXSAF1NVS0ZKX7B4RGxyZxdrzPmrJPLkHyMDqV3m3yuLXanR6ME2CG2QhgAH5VjANkgAG7CNQXZYAoE3AhAA), if you want to experiment a little].

You just have to narrow which identifiers `key` can be to one of that reference a `number` type property:

```
const someObj = {
  myValue: 123,
  otherProperty: '321'
};

getProperty(someObj, 'myValue'); //       works
getProperty(someObj, 'otherProperty'); // wails

function getProperty<T, K extends NumericProps<T>>(obj: T, key: K): number {
    return obj[key];
}

type NumericProps<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? K : never
}[keyof T];
```